# Entra External ID SwiftUI Examples

Tags: azure-entra-id

Are there any Entra ID for customers (or Entra External ID) samples using SwiftUI? I didn't see any in the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/external-id/customers/samples-ciam-all?tabs=language). The [developer center](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/identity/customers) has a [mobile app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/external-id/customers/samples-ciam-all?tabs=apptype#mobile) but I cannot find Swift or Android (Kotlin/Java) examples.